# To start app in IPhone using voice control

Tags: iphone, voice, openears

I'm starting with the IPhone app where I want to start app using voice control. The app should start when we speak word in IPhone. I'm using OpenEars framework.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible in a iPhone. Siri might have some capabilities built-in but Apple has so far not exposed any such API's to app developers. OpenEars Framework might understand what the user is talking but there is no way to open an App based on that.

For a jailbroken iPhone there is a possibility to do this. [VoiceActivator for iOS allows voice controlled commands](http://gizmodo.com/5751436/take-over-voice-control-on-ios-with-voiceactivator). But it wont run on a normal iPhone.

Hope this helps...